# How to convert youtube video player into audio player in android?

Tags: android

How can I hide the surface view of youtube player to make it as a audio player, Actually I want to play youtube video as in audio phase in my app?Any buddy have an idea

Comment: I think that it is technically possible but, it isn't in legal terms. I suggest you to read [Youtube legal terms](https://developers.google.com/youtube/terms). Especially the points 8 and 9 of the Prohibitions: `promote separately the audio or video components of any YouTube audiovisual content made available through the YouTube API;`

Comment: @GVillani82 Ok. then how can we convert Media video player into audio player and play audio in background

Comment: Basically you need a Service in which the Player can run. You can take a look [here](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-music-player/index.html?index=..%2F..%2Findex#3). The only difference is that in this specific case in this example they are using a `MediaBrowserService` because the want to expose the media content and playback control to a consumer (that in the example is the Google Auto device). In your case you need probably a simple `Service`.

Comment: @GVillani82 Thanks Buddy  you save my day :)

Comment: @GVillani82 In youtube player i got dead object exception many time and google developer personally accept it that there is some bug in latest api and they will fix that bug in their next release .

Comment: @GVillani82 So please suggest me best library for youtube player  to play you tube videos